# Handle quoted string as a json response in wso2 esb

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-esb

The backend sends a response as **"c7806e18-4284-447a-a00a-c221e3323223"** with content-type set as **application/json**. 
Which according to some is a valid json.  But WSO2 ESB gives the following error  `

```
[2017-08-08 14:12:57,037] ERROR - JsonUtil #getNewJsonPayload. Could not save JSON payload. Invalid input stream found. MessageID: urn:uuid:45214ed3-ca29-4be4-8f03-6bd1b109773d
[2017-08-08 14:12:57,053] ERROR - DeferredMessageBuilder Error building message
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Payload is not a JSON string.
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:558)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder.processDocument(JsonStreamBuilder.java:45)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:148)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:137)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:100)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:140)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:83)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:169)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:343)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:338)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:123)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:101)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:56)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:304)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue[1] in WSO2 ESB and will be fixed in the EI version 6.2. For now you may use the milestone release version[2] for your use case.

[1]https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4902

[2] https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/releases/tag/v6.2.0-m1

Comment: I am still facing this issue in version 6.4.0